# Gerar dados aleatórios dentro de um intervalo

Tags: java, random

Não consigo retornar nenhum número. Ex: Se usar "menor 1500" e "maior 5000", era para aparecer nesse intervalo caso não tivesse entrava no `while`, só que não está retornando nada.

```
public int aleatoriar(int maior, int menor) {   
    int retorno = 0;
    Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int datarecebe = (int) (lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis());  
    int recebe = datarecebe % 10000;

    if (recebe > maior || recebe < menor) {
        while(recebe >= maior && recebe <= menor) {
            retorno = recebe;
        }
    } else {
        retorno = recebe;
    }       
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Cara, você não tá alterando o recebe, como alterar o retorno?

Comment: Se você quer gerar um número aleatório, existe algum motivo para não usar o que o Java tem pronto? Até porque o que você está fazendo não é exatamente aleatório.

Comment: Existe algum forte motivo para não usar os pacotes da linguagem !?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Faça uso do que já está pronto ([`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)) e seja feliz. Funciona melhor e dá menos trabalho:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(aleatoriar(1500, 5000));
    }
    public static int aleatoriar(int minimo, int maximo) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt((maximo - minimo) + 1) + minimo;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CWaJXL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vqeqlzux-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/RandomRange2.java).

Mas se o seu problema não precisa de um número aleatório de fato e quiser insistir na sua forma:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(aleatoriar(1500, 5000));
    }
    public static int aleatoriar(int minimo, int maximo) {
        Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        return (int)(lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis() % (maximo - minimo + 1) + minimo);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iUdeLS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fyjvogmt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/RandomRange3.java).

Comment: você pode me explicar o que 'lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis()' faz no código.

Comment: @Rodolfo está pegando o horário da máquina. Para o que você deseja na outra pergunta não precisa disto, é só usar o exemplo de cima. Na verdade pode até simplificar, porque quando começa em 0 não precisa de esse nego´cio de `minimo` e `maximo`, isso é feito para deslocar o número inicial que não é necessário para você.

Answer (score 4):

Você não está alterando o valor de retorno, pois não altera o valor de recebe, para alterá-lo deveria muda o `while` para o seguinte:

```
while(recebe >= maior && recebe <= menor) {
    datarecebe = (int) (lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis());
    recebe = datarecebe % 10000;
    retorno = recebe;
}
```

Daí sim você não criará um loop infinito.

Answer (score 0):

## A partir de Java 7 você deveria usar ThreadLocalRandom

Segundo *Effective Java*, terceira edição, página 268:

> A partir de Java 7 você não mais deve usar Random. Para a maioria dos usos,
>   o gerador de números aleatórios preferido é [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). Esta classe produz números randômicos de maior qualidade, e é muito rápida.

Em consequência, o código sugerido é

```
/**
 * Gera número pseudo-aleatório na faixa fornecida.
 *
 * @param primeiro O primeiro valor da faixa.
 * @param ultimo O último valor da faixa.
 * @return Um número contido na faixa indicada, incluindo os limites.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException Se a faixa for inválida, ou seja, o
 * valor {@code ultimo} é menor que o {@code primeiro}.
 */
public static int aleatorioNaFaixa(final int primeiro, final int ultimo) {
    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    return rnd.nextInt(ultimo - primeiro + 1) + primeiro;
}
```